# Toroidal spaces inside a sphere

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

*I was studying wikipedia articles about [toruses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus) and [genuses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_%28mathematics%29) and I have following question.*

If we have a sphere (let's assume it is The Earth) and made a cylindrical passage through it (by drilling), our action  is equivalent to that of adding [a handle to the sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#/media/File:Triple_torus_illustration.png) . Created, by this operation, new surface  has genus increased by 1 and according to that, appropriate [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) and chromatic number for graphs located on this surface *(let's compare: surface of sphere 4, torus 7)*

What happens however if we encounter during   drilling an empty toroidal space (cave) inside the Earth? 
Would new created surface be equivalent to the other created by adding the handles to the sphere ? (if it is so - I doubt this- how to make the transformation between these two objects)

What happens if we  encounter  with continued drilling next toroidal empty spaces? (we can assume here that  is no connections between these empty  toruses)

**How the genus (and consequent Euler characteristic and chromatic number 
for graphs) changes with a growing number of discovered such toroidal empty spaces?**

We can  assume here that
**(the first case)**   only a single entry from the surface of Earth exists to the set of n toroidal disjoint caves 
or
**(the second case)** there are separate entries for every cave.

How situation is changed if our object to drill is a torus with toroidal caves?

*In   mathSE  search for  "empty toroidal space" gave only two links* .

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly. What exactly do you mean by "encounter an empty toroidal space"? Are you talking about drilling a new hole and in the process running into a previously drilled hole?

Comment: No, toroidal caves exist under the surface of the Earth and we, by drilling, are discovering them creating this way new continuous surface (surface of Earth+passage+cave).

Comment: So you're considering caves completely internal to the Earth, i.e. another surface disjoint from the sphere. And you're asking about the surfaces constructed by connecting these two surfaces with a handle?

Comment: Hmm, you mean passage as a handle?

Comment: Sure, your passages are just topological handles. If my interpretation is correct, then this new construction is actually trivial. The Earth + Passage + Cave is topologically equivalent to just the cave itself. You're connecting a genus $0$ surface (the Earth) to a genus $g$ surface (the cave). You end up with a genus $g$ surface again.

Comment: I ponder, maybe you are right, and what about toroidal spaces inside toruses ? Just two connected toruses ?

Comment: The question is fundamentally about connecting disjoint surfaces. In general, if you have surfaces of genus $g_1$ and $g_2$, then their [connected sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum) is a surface of genus $g_1 + g_2$. So if you connect more and more toruses, you get surfaces of higher and higher genus. Once you've connected the Earth to one cave, it effectively disappears and you no longer need to think about it anymore.

Comment: But how to smoothly transform torus inside other torus into two jointed external toruses. I can't imagine that ( see torus transforming to the cup in wikipedia    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology#/media/File:Mug_and_Torus_morph.gif   ) ?

Comment: It's probably not easy to imagine in general. But a homeomorphism is guaranteed to exist from the classification of compact surfaces. This essentially involves pulling the inner surface out from the hole they're connected at and then turning it inside out. For example, [here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aInside-out_torus_%28animated,_small%29.gif) how to turn a punctured torus inside out continuous.

Comment: I see now that it would be possible if we neglect what is inner and outer side of a surface and freely move between them. But such  surfaces are probably not equivalent from some other point of view, because without cutting them and sticking together they can't be transformed to each other.

Comment: Topologically, the two are the same. If you want to consider some other point of view, that depends on what properties you're after exactly. There is no cutting involved here. You're inverting one surface through the hole you already made when you attached the tunnel. There's no need for additional holes.

Comment: Procedure of transformation could be as follows: 1. make a cut in the surface of greater torus and cut a passage. 2. take out internal torus 3. joint two toruses and stick them. 4. stick the first cut. For graphs such procedure should give exactly the same graph. Thank you for enlightenment EuYu :)

Comment: And I have just discovered that surfaces have so called turning number (winding number), so these constructions, it seems, have the same **turning number** .

Comment: @EuYu  Although probably you are absolutely right I still ( after almost month) can't imagine how for example the earth  with toroidal cave and lying in it snake which catches his tail and additionally is hanging from the cave ceiling on $8$ wires can be transformed in a continuous way into just a disk with holes. How to take out a snake from the toroidal cave without breaking the wires not mentioning  making a snake open its mouth?  ;)

Comment: Your scenario is a bit difficult to follow and I don't know exactly what you mean. But I've already said that these things can be difficult to picture in general. However, it is a mathematical fact that a homeomorphism exists. Part of the reason algebraic topology was invented was in order to deal with these difficult to imagine scenarios in a rigorous and systematic fashion. I suggest you read a book on algebraic topology if you really want to understand what's going on.

Comment: @EuYu - Torus inside the toroidal underground cave along all the cave ( the snake catching its tail) and these tori are connected by wires (genuses?)  connecting internal part of greater torus (cave ceiling ) with external part of less torus (skin of snake). I'm sure mathematically you are right but to imagine operation of excavating such a snake onto surface to make topologically equivalent object I suppose it is impossible for human mind. But I've seen topology is paradoxical and there are many paradoxes in it.